# low RAM consuming c++ eigen solver

Tags: c++, armadillo, eigenvector, eigenvalue, lapack++

I'm newbie in *C++ programming*, but I have a task to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors (standard eigenproblem *Ax=lx*) for symmetric matrices (and hermitian)) for very large matrix of size: *binomial(L,L/2)* where *L* is about 18-22. Now I'm testing it on machine which has about 7.7 GB ram available, but at final I'll have access to PC with 64GB RAM.

I've started with *Lapack++*. At the beginning my project assume to solve this problem only for symmetrical real matrices.

This library was great. Very quick and small RAM consuming. It has an option to compute eigenvectors and place into input matrix A to save memory. It works! I thought that *Lapack++* eigensolver can handle with Hermitian matrix, but it can't for unknown reason (maybe I'm doing something wrong). My project has evolved and I should be able to calculate also this problem for Hermitian matrices.

So I've tried to change library to *Armadillo library*. It works fine, but it isn't that nice as *Lapack++* which replaces `mat A` with all `eigenvec`, but of course supports hermitian matrices.

Some statistic for L=14

- *Lapack++*  RAM 126MB time 7.9s eigenval + eigenvectors
- *Armadillo* RAM 216MB time 12s eigenval
- *Armadillo* RAM 396MB time 15s eigenval+eigenvectors

Let's do some calculation: `double` variable is about *8B*. My matrix has size
*binomial(14,7) = 3432*, so in the ideal case it should have *3432^2*8/1024^2 = 89 MB*.

My question is: is it posible to modify or inforce *Armadillo* to do a nice trick as *Lapack++*? *Armadillo* uses `LAPACK` and `BLAS` routines. Or maybe someone can recomemnd another approach to this problem using another library?

P.S.:
My matrix is really sparse. It has about *2 * binomial(L,L/2)* non-zero elements.
I've tried to compute this with `SuperLU` in CSC format but It wasn't very effective, for L=14 -> RAM 185MB, but time 135s.

Comment: Have you considered using the SLEPcEigenSolver with PETSc?

Comment: @symphonic I've heard about it, but I think this library will be too difficult for me. If I have time I'll try to test it.

Comment: In LAPACK you have the routine zheev (http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/cxxlapack/netlib/lapack/zheev.f.html) for computing the eigenvalues and -vectors of a hermitian matrix.  However, you seem to be right in Lapack++ it seems they are not supporting complex valued matrices (or at least not hermitian).  So maybe it is a good idea call the LAPACK routine directly from C++.

Comment: @MichaelLehn Thank you for the reply. I know that LAPACK has such as routine, but I don't learn how to call it directly in C++ yet, so I will try to learn how to call it first! :)

Comment: In FLENS there are C++ wrappers for LAPACK.  Including for zheev.  So basically you can rip the out of FLENS.  You also can first check if FLENS is doing the job for you.  Here (http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/examples/lapack-syev.html) is an example for computing eigenvalues/-vectors for a symmetric matrix.  For hermitian matrices there's only an example (https://github.com/michael-lehn/FLENS/blob/public/flens/examples/lapack-complex-heev.cc) in github but not yet in the online tutorial.  These examples from the tutorial only setup small demo-cases.

Comment: But it is still a good idea to start with these so that you are sure how to link with an external LAPACK (basically you just compile with -DUSE_CXXLAPACK and add the usual linker options).  For large examples have a look at the tutorial on how to setup large matrices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Lapackpp and Armadillo rely on Lapack to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of complex matrices. The Lapack library provides different way to perform these operations for complex hermitian matrices.

- The function [`zgeev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/dba/zgeev_8f.html) does not care about the matrix being Hermitian. This function is called by the Lapackpp library for matrices of type `LaGenMatComplex` in the function [`LaEigSolve`](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/html/laslv_8h.html#086357d17e9cdcaec69ab7db76998769). The function [`eig_gen()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_gen) of the Armadillo library calls this function.
- The function [`zheev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f.html) is dedicated to complex Hermitian matrices. It first call ZHETRD to reduce Hermitian matrix to tridiagonal form. Depending on whether the eigenvectors are needed, it then uses a [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (if needed). The function [`eig_sym()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) of the Armadillo library call this function if the method `std` is selected.
- The function [`zheevd()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dae/zheevd_8f.html) does the same thing as `zheev()` if the eigenvectors are not required. Otherwise, it makes use of a divide and conquert algorithm (see [`zstedc()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zstedc.f.html<code>)). The function [`eig_sym()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) of the Armadillo library call this function if the method `dc` is selected. Since the divide and conquer proved to be faster for large matrices, it is now the default method.

Functions with more options are available in the Lapack library. (see [`zheevr()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/dd2/zheevr_8f.html) or [`zheevx`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d95/zheevx_8f.html)). If you want to keep a dense matrix format, you can also try the `ComplexEigenSolver` of the Eigen library.

Here is a little C++ test using the C wrapper `LAPACKE` of the Lapack library. It is compiled by `g++ main.cpp  -o main2 -L /home/...../lapack-3.5.0 -llapacke -llapack -lblas`

```
#include <iostream>

#include <complex>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

#include "lapacke.h"

#undef complex
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //int n = 3432;

    int n = 600;

    std::complex<double> *matrix=new std::complex<double>[n*n];
    memset(matrix, 0, n*n*sizeof(std::complex<double>));
    std::complex<double> *matrix2=new std::complex<double>[n*n];
    memset(matrix2, 0, n*n*sizeof(std::complex<double>));
    std::complex<double> *matrix3=new std::complex<double>[n*n];
    memset(matrix3, 0, n*n*sizeof(std::complex<double>));
    std::complex<double> *matrix4=new std::complex<double>[n*n];
    memset(matrix4, 0, n*n*sizeof(std::complex<double>));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        matrix[i*n+i]=42;
        matrix2[i*n+i]=42;
        matrix3[i*n+i]=42;
        matrix4[i*n+i]=42;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        matrix[i*n+(i+1)]=20;
        matrix2[i*n+(i+1)]=20;
        matrix3[i*n+(i+1)]=20;
        matrix4[i*n+(i+1)]=20;

        matrix[(i+1)*n+i]=20;
        matrix2[(i+1)*n+i]=20;
        matrix3[(i+1)*n+i]=20;
        matrix4[(i+1)*n+i]=20;
    }

    double* w=new double[n];//eigenvalues

    //the lapack function zheev
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    LAPACKE_zheev(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'V','U', n,reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(matrix), n, w);
    t = clock() - t;
    cout<<"zheev : "<<((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds"<<endl;
    cout<<"largest eigenvalue="<<w[n-1]<<endl;

    std::complex<double> *wc=new std::complex<double>[n];
    std::complex<double> *vl=new std::complex<double>[n*n];
    std::complex<double> *vr=new std::complex<double>[n*n];

    t = clock();
    LAPACKE_zgeev(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'V','V', n,reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(matrix2), n, reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(wc),reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(vl),n,reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(vr),n);
    t = clock() - t;
    cout<<"zgeev : "<<((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds"<<endl;
    cout<<"largest eigenvalue="<<wc[0]<<endl;

    t = clock();
    LAPACKE_zheevd(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'V','U', n,reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(matrix3), n, w);
    t = clock() - t;
    cout<<"zheevd : "<<((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds"<<endl;
    cout<<"largest eigenvalue="<<w[n-1]<<endl;

    t = clock();
    LAPACKE_zheevd(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'N','U', n,reinterpret_cast< __complex__ double*>(matrix4), n, w);
    t = clock() - t;
    cout<<"zheevd (no vector) : "<<((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds"<<endl;
    cout<<"largest eigenvalue="<<w[n-1]<<endl;

    delete[] w;
    delete[] wc;
    delete[] vl;
    delete[] vr;
    delete[] matrix;
    delete[] matrix2;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I have of my computer is :

```
zheev : 2.79 seconds
largest eigenvalue=81.9995
zgeev : 10.74 seconds
largest eigenvalue=(77.8421,0)
zheevd : 0.44 seconds
largest eigenvalue=81.9995
zheevd (no vector) : 0.02 seconds
largest eigenvalue=81.9995
```

These tests could have been performed by using the Armadillo library. Calling directly the Lapack library might allow you to gain some memory, but wrappers of Lapack can be efficient on this aspect as well.

The real question is whether you need all the eigenvectors, all the eigenvalues or only the largest eigenvalues. Because there are really efficient methods in the last case. Take a look at the Arnoldi/[Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) itterative algorithms. Huge memory gains are possible if the matrix is sparce since only matrix-vector products are performed : there is no need to keep the dense format. This is what is done in the SlepC library, which makes use of the sparce matrix formats of Petsc. [Here is an example of Slepc](http://slepc.upv.es/documentation/current/src/eps/examples/tutorials/ex1.c.html) which can be used as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has same problem as I in the future there are some tips after I found the solution (thank for all that posted some answers or clues!).

On the intel site you can found some nice examples which are written in Fortran and C. For example hermitian eigenvalue problem routine zheev():
https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/zheev_ex.c.htm

To make it works in C++ you should edit some lines in that code:

In prototype functions declaration do similar for all functions: `extern void zheev( ... )` change to `extern "C" {void zheev( ... )}`

Change calling lapack's function adding `_` symbol for example: `zheev( ... )` to `zheev_( ... )` (make it for all in code simply by substitution, but I don't why it works. I figured it out by making some experiments.)

Optionally you can convert `printf` function to a standard stream `std::cout` and replace included headers `stdio.h` to `iostream`.

To compile run command like: `g++ test.cpp -o test -llapack -lgfortran -lm -Wno-write-strings`

About the last option `-Wno-write-strings`, I don't now what it's doing, but probably there're problems with intel's example when they put string not char in calling function `zheev( "Vectors", "Lower", ... )`